# Automatic DNS Server over an Access Point on Windows

Tags: dns, server, wifi

I just created and Access Point and a DNS Server running and listening on port 53 of my current laptop, I would like that everyone connected to this AP use this DNS Server I created and not another one... but when theirs systems get connected, they select an automatic DNS server and not mine....
Is there a function or some command to define that the DNS server for my current AP Connection will be this one I created before??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as forcing another system to chose whatever DNS you want. Thinking about it makes clear, that this is a good thing: Out of my cold dead hands may you pry my ability to switch to 8.8.8.8 if my ISP's DNS again fails in an absurd way.

If you insist on doing this to your users, you must step down to the UDP (and possibly TCP) layers: Create a few `iptables` rules on the AP (or if it does no routing on a router above it), that DNATs all requests to port 53 to your DNS.

Be warned though: Breaking the DNS system on purpose (whether it is done for monetization as with some ISPs or trying to solve another problem) is not something you should do lightly.